# Reverse text in Java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I need help.
I need to reverse only Latin symbols in text, all other symbols should stay at the same place.
But I have some additional " " in result. I think it's because I use setLength in String builder, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Example of how it should works:

input: `Sra1katr#/ g1gl, pl2`

output: `rta1karS#/ l1gg, lp2`

**Here is my code :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter text for reverse");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = scan.nextLine();
            
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            
    char[] alphabetArray = alphabet.toCharArray();
    List<Character> alphabetList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c : alphabetArray) {
        alphabetList.add(c);
    }
                    
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    StringBuilder invertedSentece = new StringBuilder("");
            
    for (String word : words) {
        StringBuilder invertedWord = new StringBuilder("");
        invertedWord.setLength(word.length());
                
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (alphabetList.contains(word.charAt(i))) {
                int c = word.length() - 1 - i;
                invertedWord = invertedWord.insert(c, word.charAt(i));
            } else {
                invertedWord = invertedWord.deleteCharAt(i);
                invertedWord = invertedWord.insert(i, word.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        invertedSentece = invertedSentece.append(invertedWord).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(invertedSentece);
}
```

Comment: Yes, what does "reverse only Latin symbols in text, all other symbols should stay at the same place" mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This line is the origin of the error:

```
invertedSentece = invertedSentece.append(invertedWord).append(" ");
```

you add `" "` after every word. You could simply not add it after the last word :)

And old trick to achieve that is to introduce a variable `boolean first = true;` before the word loop and say `fitrst = false;` at the end of the word loop and insert the " " at the beginning of the word loop, like this:

```
boolean first = true;
for (String word : words) {
    if (!first) {
        invertedSentece = invertedSentece.append(" ");
    }
    ...
    invertedSentece = invertedSentece.append(invertedWord);
    first = false;
}
```

Plus, using a list for the alphabet is extremely inefficient. Ususally, a Set instead of a List would be the obvious answer but in this case, you could simply write a static method

```
private static boolean isInLatinAlphabet(char c) {
    return
        (c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z') ||
        (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z');
}
```

This works because char is a numeric type and Java uses UTF-16 as the internal representation for char, Character, and String.

Therefore, like in ASCII and unlike in EBCDIC, A-Z, a-z, and 0-9 form sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works, refer explanation in the end:

Input: afsg%gag thy@sdg$

Output: gagg%sfa gds@yht$

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter text for reverse");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = scan.nextLine();

    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    char[] alphabetArray = alphabet.toCharArray();
    List<Character> alphabetList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c : alphabetArray) {
        alphabetList.add(c);
    }

    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    StringBuilder invertedSentece = new StringBuilder(); // We don't need "" to initialize a stringbuilder

    for (String word : words) {
        StringBuilder invertedWord = new StringBuilder(); // We don't need "" to initialize a stringbuilder//           invertedWord.setLength(word.length()); 
        int deleteIndex = 1; // Use an index and increase the counter everytime we find a latin letter
        HashMap<Integer, Character> storeLatin = new HashMap<>(); // Creating a hashmap to store latin letters in a
                                                                    // word

        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (alphabetList.contains(word.charAt(i))) {
                int c = word.length() - deleteIndex - i;
                invertedWord = invertedWord.insert(c, word.charAt(i));
            } else {
                storeLatin.put(Integer.valueOf(i), Character.valueOf(word.charAt(i)));
                deleteIndex++;
            }
        }

        // Loop to read letters from hashmap and add them at the specified index
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Character> item : storeLatin.entrySet()) {
            invertedWord.insert(item.getKey().intValue(), item.getValue());
        }

        invertedSentece = invertedSentece.append(invertedWord).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(invertedSentece.substring(0, invertedSentece.length() - 1));
}
```

Explanation:

There is a problem with the else statement logic.

Lets take an example abe#hy, while reversing the string we move

y at 0 index
h at 1 index
And now we assign # at index 3 and the current invertedWord is "yh #"

In the next iteration when we push another letter e into the stringbuilder, it will just keep pushing everything to the right - "yhe #"

Second point is deleting a character at an index in StringBuilder and then adding items at all over indices except this index would still leave a blank space in our result. To avoid this problem, we need to maintain a counter of number of latin letters and use it to calculate the other indices (refer the use of deleteIndex variable).

Comment: Are you sure that last line should have invertedSentece.length() - 1) and not invertedSentece.length()?                                                                                  System.out.println(invertedSentece.substring(0, invertedSentece.length() - 1));

Comment: I was trying to get rid of the extra space at the end of the last word we are adding from this code
invertedSentece = invertedSentece.append(invertedWord).append(" ");

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String reverseOnlyLetters(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < str.length(); ) {
        if (j >= 0) {
            if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(j))) {
                if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) {
                    buf.append(str.charAt(j--));
                    i++;
                } else
                    buf.append(str.charAt(i++));
            } else
                j--;
        } else
            buf.append(str.charAt(i++));
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

**Output:**

```
System.out.println(reverseOnlyLetters("a_bc_DEF_ghij"));        // j_ih_gFE_Dcba
System.out.println(reverseOnlyLetters("!@#$%^&*()_+"));         // !@#$%^&*()_+
System.out.println(reverseOnlyLetters("afsg%gag thy@sdg$"));    // gdsy%htg agg@sfa$
```

Answer (score 0):

How i did it:

```
String revers(String inputText) {
    
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(inputText.split(" ")));
    StringBuilder invertedSentence = new StringBuilder();

    for (String word : words){
        Map<Integer, Character> storeLetter = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
        int deleteIndex = 1;
        StringBuilder invertedWord = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(i))) {                   
            
                int c = word.length() - deleteIndex - i;
                invertedWord = invertedWord.insert(c, word.charAt(i));
                    
    }
            else {
                storeLetter.put(i, word.charAt(i));
                deleteIndex++;
                        }  

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Character> letter : storeLetter.entrySet()) {
        invertedWord.insert(letter.getKey().intValue(), letter.getValue());         
    }
    invertedSentence.append(invertedWord);
    invertedSentence.append(" ");
    }
    return invertedSentence.toString().trim();
}
```